# Codeigniter: Is calling a model from a helpler a bad idea?

Tags: codeigniter, dynamic, view, model, helper

I have a menu on my page that is loaded on every page. The menu data is fetched from the database through a model. My first thought was to call the model from the controller, and then pass it to the view on every page. But that results in "messy" code, if i ever forget to pass the menu data to the view, it will result in an ugly error (or just no menu items).

So i came up with the solution of fetching the menu items through a helper, and then just call the helper function from the view. It makes more sense, because i only have the code in one place (the menu view).

My views are set up in this way: Controller calls "page" view which then loads the header view, menu view, the appropriate content view, and lastly the footer view. The helper is only called from one place, the menu view.

Normally you can't even load models from helpers, but i did a workaround using $i = get_instance(); and then loading the model through that instance; $i->load->model().

I have a feeling this is not the way to go, but are there any better ways?

**Edit: To put it in a better way:**

I want:
view -> get data -> display

not:
controller -> get data -> pass to view -> display

I'm just not sure if that's "Ok" to do, since it disregards the MVC model completely.

Comment: I think you should look at extending your controller. That way you could load the menu data in the base constructor and it would always be avialable, and ther's nothing for you to forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the solution is easier than you think.

If now you're doing something like this in your helper:

```
create_menu()
{
    $menu_items = $this->db->query('')->result();
    // creating the menu here
}
```

You could just change the function to accept input like this and still follow the MVC pattern.

**Helper**

```
create_menu($input)
{
    $menu_items = $input;
    // creating the menu here
}
```

**Model:**

```
get_menu_data()
{
   $menu_items = $this->db->query('')->result();
}
```

Does this make sense?

**Edit:**

This is the way I did it on one of the projects:

I extended my standard controller. Within the constructor of that controller I called the model and grabbed the data:

```
$this->menu_items = $this->some_model->get_menu_items();
```

Within a view `nav.php`:

```
if(!empty($this->subnav_item))
{
   // Generate menu
}
```

This way the MVC is intact, but I dont have to worry about passing variables.

**EDIT 2**

**How to extend the standard controller:**

Create a file `MY_Controller.php` in `application/core`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $menu_items = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('some_model_that_you_always_use');
        $this->load->library('some_library_that_you_always_use');
        $this->menu_items = $this->some_model->get_menu_items();
    }

}
```

When you create a new controller, you extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller` like this:

```
 class Something extends MY_Controller {

 }
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but i don't think you understand the problem. If i were to use your example, i would still have to grab the menu data from the model in the controller, and then pass it to the helper from the view. I don't want to have to pass the menu data from the controller to the view, i want to GET the menu data from the view (or a helper in this case) to avoid having to pass the menu data to the view on every page. I'm not sure if it makes sense, it's hard to explain.

Comment: I updated my question, please see my edit for a simpler explanation. :)

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you have `$this->menu_items = $this->some_model->get_menu_items();` in the constructor of every controller class? I suppose that makes it easier, because i only have to load it once per controller. But what if i have several controllers? I still have to load it several times in different controllers then. But it's much better than my original idea, if there's no better way i'll definitely use it!

Comment: No, not in every controller, but in the new "default controller". The data does get loaded every time, but you have to load in only once. See the difference? I edited my answer with a small "how-to"

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks for the explanation as well. I read about it but didn't quite figure it out before. Danneth posted the same answer but you beat him to it, so i'll mark yours as accepted.

Comment: While i don't get any errors, the $menu_items var isn't available in the extended classes or from the view. I don't get any errors, but it just doesn't work. New class in application/core: `class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller` and when i extend it from application/controllers: `class Home extends MY_Controller`. "var" was depricated in PHP5 i think, so i have it set as public instead. Here's the relevant code: pastebin.com/9G4daCAd

Comment: Oops! I meant to say i do get an error about the variable not existing, but other than that it behaves as normal. The error is shown in the pastebin link. Sorry about the spam...

Comment: I tried to call the variable directly, but i need to access it through $this, like `$this->genres_for_menu`. It works now. Thanks for the help, and sorry about the spam once again!

Comment: You're right, var should be public and since it's a class property you need to access it via $this indeed. Glad it works. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

So I found a quick example to cut-n-paste (in this case I have a model called `login` autoloaded, but you can of course do that manually)

In the file `core\MY_Controller.php`

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    protected $login_ok;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /* --- Check if user is logged in --- */
        $this->config->load('adldap', TRUE);
        $data->login_ok = $this->login->check_login(TRUE);

        $this->load->vars($data);
    }
}
```

If you then extend your controller with this. You will have `$login_ok` available in your view.

This way you can be sure that the required variables are always prepared and you only have to write the code in one place

Comment: That sounds about right! Would i have to extend Admin_Controller instead of CI_Controller on my controllers if i  use this? Also, i assume you mean `application/core/My_Controller.php` right?

Comment: Well, this is what I was talking about. The copy-paste is wrong because Admin_Controller should be called MY_Controller or vice versa.

Comment: @robert: You can name it whatever you want as long as the file is called `MY_Controller.php`. I have three different classes in `MY_Controller.php` namely `class Admin_Controller`, `class User_Controller` and `class Public_Controller`.

Comment: @qwerty: You are right, that's the file, and you would extend your new controller instead of `CI_Controller`

Comment: @danneth you're right. Somehow I was convinced that the names needed to correspond like in controllers or models, but they don't. +1 4U :)

Comment: @Robert Given the regular structure it would have made sense with a structure like `/application/core/my_controllers/fancy_controller.php` for the class `fancy_controller`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that nothing about the MVC pattern prohibits a View from contacting a Model directly. That's just a convention that seems common with CodeIgniter.

I suggest that in this case, your menu view should load the menu data directly from the menu model.